# How to cancel a command inside a script without exiting the script itself?

Tags: bash

When running a script with some lines not too important for the script to finish, how do I cancel a specific command without killing the entire script?

Normally I would invoke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, but when I do that with that script, the entire script ends prematurely.  Is there a way (e.g. options placed inside the script) to allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> just for the command at hand?

A bit of a background:
I have my `~/.bash_profile` to run `ssh-add` as part of it, but if I cancel it, I would like to get the echo lines following the "error 130" of `ssh-add` being shown to remind me to run it manually before any connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for traps:

```
trap terminate_foo SIGINT

terminate_foo() {
  echo "foo terminated"
  bar
}

foo() {
  while :; do 
    echo foo
    sleep 1
  done
}

bar() {
  while :; do 
    echo bar
    sleep 1
  done
}

foo
```

Output:

```
./foo
foo
foo
foo
^C foo terminated # here ctrl+c pressed
bar
bar
...
```

---

Function `foo` is executed until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, and then continues the execution, in this case the function `bar`.

Comment: It's a TRAP!  But a good one.  After rebuilding my `.bash_profile`, it works like described.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it  helped.

Comment: "It's a TRAP!" Haha I get it now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /bin/bash

trap handle_sigint SIGINT

ignore_sigint='no'

handle_sigint () {
        if [ 'yes' = "$ignore_sigint" ]; then
                echo 'Caught SIGINT: Script continues...'
        else
                echo 'Caught SIGINT: Script aborts...'
                exit 130 # 128+2; SIGINT is 2
        fi
}

echo 'running short commands...'
sleep 1
sleep 1

ignore_sigint='yes'
echo 'running long commands...'
sleep 10
ignore_sigint='no'
echo 'End of script.'
```